# SSRS Datadriven subscriptions Limitations

Tags: pdf, report, ssrs-2012, subscription, data-driven

I am trying to generate 10000 pdf reports into the windows file share location using SSRS data driven subscription methodology and I found that when I run for small bathces and it works and it surely fail when I give 10000 at a time. This behavior is unpredictable and not able to scale the solution.  Ex:
When I put 10000 load it generates 2700 and fails rest but when I try to run failed records in another batch then it gets me the PDFs. It fails sometime with small batch sizes also. No proper reason logged.

Thanks

Comment: Here is the error log:

Comment: This may be due to a connection failure, timeout or low disk condition within the database. ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Could not allocate space for object 'dbo.SnapshotData'.'IX_SnapshotData' in database 'ReportServerTempDB' because the 'PRIMARY' filegroup is full. Create disk space by deleting unneeded files, dropping objects in the filegroup, adding additional files to the filegroup, or setting autogrowth on for existing files in the filegroup   .